# How to get radiobuttons 2x2?

Tags: html

I am creating a multiple choice quiz with 4 answers per question. Instead of the answers being 1 answer per line I'd like them to be 2 questions each line, so there is less room needed in the div tag that they are placed in. How can I do this?

```
case 3:echo"  <h6>How many albums has Marley released?:</h6>
<h6><input type='radio' name='Q6' value='16' />Sixteen (16)</h6>
<h6><input type='radio' name='Q6' value='5' />Five (5)</h6>
<h6><input type='radio' name='Q6' value='3' />Three (3)</h6>
<h6><input type='radio' name='Q6' value='24' />Twenty-Four (24)</h6> ";
break;
```

Comment: this is more specific to html/css rather than PHP

Comment: A container having `width: 400px;` and checkboxes having `display: inline-block; width: 200px;`.

Answer (score 0):

in css

```
h6:nth-child(1) {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;

}
h6 {
    width:50%;
    display:block;
    float:left;   
}
```

Comment: that is kind of what i want but this is what happened :s [IMG](http://i41.tinypic.com/b80cog.png)[/IMG]

Comment: put a wrap the echo in a div ... nth-child selector requires a parent, that's how i'm isolating the question from the answers. you could also throw a class on the questions and replace the nth-child selector with that.

Comment: i dont quite understand what youre meaning? :\

Comment: for example `<h6 class='question'>How many albums has Marley released?:</h6>` then change the first style rule to : `h6.question {display:block;width:100%;clear:both;}`